# Is there any way to print it in python(python bridging on prolog)?

Tags: python, prolog, ffi, swi-prolog

I am trying to run the prolog queries from the python program by using pyswip.
Suppose i have a program like this,

```
from pyswip import Prolog
p = Prolog()
p.retractall('rule1(_,_)')
p.retractall('rule2(_,_)')
p.retractall('rule3(_,_)')
p.assertz('rule2(X):- writeln(\'in rule2\': X)')
p.assertz('rule1(X,Y):- rule2(X), writeln(\'rule2 exectued\'),rule3(Y)')
p.assertz('rule3(Y):- writeln(\'in rule3\': Y)')
print(list(p.query('rule1(1,2)')))
```

now what i want is that all those writeln rules which will print in prolog, i want that to be printed in the python terminal.is there any way to do it ?

Comment: What does this currently do when you run it?

Comment: prints nothing,empty list. output:- [ { } ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me this behaves as follows:

```
>>> print(list(p.query('rule1(1,2)')))
in rule2:1
rule2 exectued
in rule3:2
[{}]
```

Your `writeln` statements are executed as expected, the output is printed to the Python terminal. Is the output different for you? Do you want it to be different?

**Edit (see comments below):** When Python is not run directly in a terminal but rather in a Jupyter notebook or similar, the Prolog output can get lost. In that case, the Prolog query can be wrapped in `with_output_to(atom(PrologOutput), ...)`, which will capture the Prolog code's output in an atom (a Python string):

```
>>> print(list(p.query('with_output_to(atom(PrologOutput), rule1(1,2))')))
[{'PrologOutput': 'in rule2:1\nrule2 exectued\nin rule3:2\n'}]
```

Comment: I ran but it is not printing the output it only prints the last line of your code. Is it printing for you?

Comment: Yes. Specifically, if I put your code into a file `foo.py` and run `python foo.py`, I get the three lines of Prolog output and then the `[{}]` from Python. I have Python 3.6.9, pyswip 0.2.10, and SWI-Prolog 7.6.4.

Comment: yes it worked thnx a lot. but there's one thing i cant understand, when i ran this code on jupyter notebook in file with .ipynb extension it didnt worked like i said earlier. but when i ran this code with .py extension on the linux terminal it worked.

Comment: Ah, you should have said right away that you are using Jupyter, not "real" Python in a terminal. You can try to run the query as `p.query('with_output_to(atom(PrologOutput), rule1(1,2))')`, then the result will contain a Prolog atom (a Python string) called `PrologOutput` containing the output.

Comment: ohh will be very useful thnx a lot.

Comment: hey can you share some resources which will be helpful, some documentation on using prolog in python, pyswip. since i am a beginner in this area.

Comment: I'm glad this seems to help. Sorry, I know Prolog and I know some Python but I'm not experienced with pyswip either.